# Как сменить время в UNIX?

Tags: unix

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой командой надо воспользоваться, чтобы сменить время? Команда **date** меняет и дату и время, а мне нужно, чтобы только время менялось... Мне это нужно для лабораторной работы "команды Unix".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы изменить только время, воспользуйтесь той же командой date в формате

```
date +%T -s "hh:mm:ss"
```

где hh - часы, mm - минуты, ss - секунды. Например:

```
date +%T -s "03:30:00"
```

- выставить время на полчетвертого ночи.

Comment: огромное вам спасибо

Comment: Не знаю зачем это...